# SELECT query with same label node using PGQL

Tags: oracle-graph

We are trying to write PGQL select query on PG View(version 21.4) to retrieve all nodes using label.

We had being using the following link as our PGQL guideline. https://pgql-lang.org/spec/1.4/#writing-simple-queries

Node Table:

- Database table: NODE
- Columns: ID, LABEL, PROPERTIES, CREATEDBY, CREATEDDATETIME

Example select query: `SELECT n.* FROM MATCH (n:DATA) ON GRAPH`

ERROR: `vertex label does not exist.`

It will return result if :DATA is remove. What would had cause the error since it was working on PGS. Any solution or workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you check if the label (= DATA) exists in the graph using the query below, and attach the result?


SELECT LABEL(n), COUNT(n)
FROM MATCH (n) ON GRAPH
GROUP BY LABEL(n)

Comment: label (=NODE). which is the database table name.

Comment: Could you attach the result of the query above so we can make sure that the labels are visible via the PG view?

Comment: I am sorry for unclear response.
Results:
[
 {
  "LABEL(n)": "NODE",
  "COUNT(n)": 9
 }
]

Comment: According to the result above, it seems vertex with label "DATA" does not exist. So the error is correct, maybe?